# How to remove Tab Header and Stretch the TabControl so no white space is showed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, tabcontrol

I'm completely new to the `WPF .NET Core`, I'm trying to implement my current software from `WinForms` to `WPF`. I'm currently stuck here:
I removed the `TabControl Header`, but I don't like that space showed in the picture.
[image]

Defining The Main Grid

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

SubMain Grid

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

In WinForms I had to override the Draw method, but I'm currently looking for a solution for WPF?

P.S Please if you are planning to give negative vote, explain where I did wrong.. Thank you!

For full XML code click [Here](https://pastebin.com/GwnkCBDf)

Comment: make sure to post a [mcve] which actually includes TabControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to WPF. Here is a style I use for `TabControl` when I want to control the selected tab internally without letting the user change it:

```
...
xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=PresentationFramework"
...

<Style TargetType="TabControl">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="cm:DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you take a look at the documentation on [`Visibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility) you should note the difference between `Hidden` (which you are using in your code) and `Collapsed` (which I am using in mine). `Hidden` is why you are still getting empty space.

I use `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode` as a trigger so that the tabs still show up while in design mode. That way I can still click between them when designing the interface.